# Saving in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, save

I'm new to Objective-C programming on the Mac. I have a Mac application and I have created a class 'Product', which contains variables such as 'ID', 'Name', 'Price' etc. When a new 'Product' is created in my application, I need to be able to save it. I have looked at various methods of saving, but I am unsure of which to use. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How long do you need to save it for? How many products will there be? Synching? Cloud stored? 'Searchability'?

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear. I will just be saving them locally i.e. no cloud storage. The app is just a personal application. Number of products will be up to about 750. I would require them to be stored permanently, with the ability to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

To save/read your object in a file you have to do something called [serializing and deserializing your object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). For doing this, you have to decide if you want to use an existing file format (recommended) or create your own one.

**Using an existing format -**
A good practice is to use an existing format like [XML](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language), what makes it easier to read the data from a different application later. The contents of your XML could look like this:

```
<products>
    <product>
        <id>24</id>
        <name>Playstation 3</name>
        <price>200</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>52</id>
        <name>Xbox 360</name>
        <price>150</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <id>64</id>
        <name>Pooh, the bear</name>
        <price>10</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

This structure can be easily read by any other application later. To get the contents of your objects in a structure like this, you could either use a [serialization library like wonderxml](https://code.google.com/p/wonderxml/), or you write your own serialization methods that are capable of serializing and deserializing your object. Finally you write the XML you created with any of these methods into a file for example [with the NSFileManager](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Objective-C).

**Creating your own** textual or binary format requires defining your own file format and therefore writing your own serialization and deserialization methods.

A textual format is written into the file textually, just the way you define it. For example delimiting each attribute with ',' and each product entry with ';'. Here you have to take care of the encoding and escaping the characters you use as delimiters. The contents could look like this (note the backslash as escape character):

```
24,Playstation 3,200;52,Xbox 360,150;64,Pooh\, the bear,10
```

Creating your own binary format requires a bit more knowledge about binary files. You have to define what contents are in which order and take care of the encoding. Your format could for example look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------|
| attribute  | length  | notice                        | 
|------------|---------|-------------------------------|
| id         | 4 bytes | number, note [endianess][5]   |
| nameLength | 4 bytes | length of the following name  |
| name       | ? bytes | take length from previous     | 
| price      | 4 bytes |                               |
-------------------------------------------------------|
```

When de/serializing, you simply have to read/write the objects according to the specification you created. This method creates the most compact files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Core Data. I'd start with the basic Xcode master-detail template which will create the model and a sample entity for you together with a view for listing all of your items and adding new ones and a detail view where you can see the, shocker, details.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easy to make a NSDictionary out of a Product ?

Would all the values in that dictionary be subclasses of NSString, NSData, NSArray, or NSDictionary ?

If so, you can create a NSArray than contains one such NSDictionary for every one of your product.

The method [writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a) will allow you to save a file from this NSArray.
The method `initWithContentsOfFile:` will allow you to read bak that file and create a NSArray out of it. You will then be able to take every NSDictionary and recreate a Product out of it.

If you can't make your data fit into that scheme, you will have to use a more elaborate method of serialization.